# CSS3 zoom animation with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to zoom into an image on hover but to hide all the overflow of the image that spills over the containing div. So any part of the image that spills outside the container is just hidden.

```
#portfolioWrapper img{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

#portfolioWrapper img:hover{
  opacity: .7;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Md49g/ (Any image when zoomed outside of the dotted boarder to be hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden;` on the container itself, not the image.

```css
#portfolioWrapper{
    width:400px;
    border: 3px dotted green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Md49g/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your image with a container, in the below intro-image-box is the container.

```
<div class="intro-image-box">
   <img src="./resources/img/intro-office.jpg" alt="Intor office Image">
</div>
```

Now in your CSS file

```
.intro-image-box{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.intro-image-box img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 1%;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.intro-image-box img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```